# How to write digits with backslash and avoid unicodes symbols

Tags: variables, tcl

I have variable which is a path where output file of operations will be saved. Foe example

```
set ResultPath "G:\\KSimonov\\PerGeos\\2. TCL Scripts\\Results\\"
```

After operation I need to export data from my modified file and put in folder which is given by variable ResultPath. I want to call it using digits. For example,

```
"G:\\KSimonov\\PerGeos\\2. TCL Scripts\\Results\\1.am"
```

where `.am` is format of file. And the problem is that if I put filename like that he gives unicode symbols:

```
echo "$ResultPath\1.am" 
G:\KSimonov\PerGeos\2. TCL Scripts\Results\.am
```

Could you please advise how to avoid this situation?
the way I found is use unicodes of digits like

```
echo "$ResultPath\u0031"
G:\KSimonov\PerGeos\2. TCL Scripts\Results\1
```

Comment: The unicode symbol seems to have gone missing when posting here, at least as far as I can see. What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to quote the backslashes to avoid them being interpreted.  You can either do:

```
set ResultPath "G:\\KSimonov\\PerGeos\\2. TCL Scripts\\Results\\"
```

or:

```
set ResultPath {G:\KSimonov\PerGeos\2. TCL Scripts\Results\}
```

For details see Tcl's quoting and substitution rules at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: I am sorry. I added wrong path here. Indeed it is "G:\\KSimonov\\PerGeos\\2. TCL Scripts\\Results\\". In my code I used that variant

Answer (score 0):

> I have variable which is a path where output file of operations will
>   be saved

Make sure that you build up the path properly, rather than embedding it as a naked string that requires protection later on:

```
% set ResultPath [file join G: KSimonov PerGeos {2. TCL Scripts} Results]
G:/KSimonov/PerGeos/2. TCL Scripts/Results
```

Check out: [file join](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M19) and [file split](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm#M35).

Comment: I don't quite follow your excursus to `echo`, I must admit, but to obtain a (Win) native file name then from the (Tcl) generic one in `ResultPath`, use `file nativename $ResultPath` (e.g., to `puts` it to stdout or the like).

Comment: I am sorry. I added wrong path here. Indeed it is "G:\\KSimonov\\PerGeos\\2. TCL Scripts\\Results\\". In my code I used that variant

Comment: You have received different pointers already, all applicable. The reason `echo` and `puts` swallow `1` is because of the missing backslash escape in `echo "$ResultPath\1.am"`. Change this to `echo "$ResultPath\\1.am"` and your expectation will be served. But better is to revise your implementation on that matter.

Comment: Dump my previous comment. I meant to write: Change this to `echo ${ResultPath}1.am` and your expectation will be served.

Comment: As for the unicode character, that you might have observed: your way of "string-assembling" the path leads to the following backslash substitution: `echo \\\1.am`. This is because the first two backslashes come with `ResultPath`, the third one with the suffix `\1.am`. This will be backslash-substituted as: \\ -> \, \1 -> octal unicode for `\u0001` ... as this is not a printable character, simplistically speaking, you see it "disappear": `.am`.

Answer (score 0):

In the invocation

```
echo "$ResultPath\1.am"
```

the backslash must be escaped just like when a filename is given:

```
echo "$ResultPath\\1.am"
```

There is no reason to use backslashes in file paths even in Windows (I never do). Just use

```
set ResultPath "G:/KSimonov/PerGeos/2. TCL Scripts/Results"
```

and

```
echo $ResultPath/1.am
```

or even

```
echo [file join $ResultPath 1.am]
```

If you want to print it out and make it look like a Windows path:

```
puts [file nativename $ResultPath]
G:\KSimonov\PerGeos\2. TCL Scripts\Results

puts [file nativename [file join $ResultPath 1.am]]
G:\KSimonov\PerGeos\2. TCL Scripts\Results\1.am
```

Inside your script, the backslashes are just in the way.